# Bash: Sed replacing all occurrences except one

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace all patterns of either `AllowUsers`, `#AllowUsers` or `# AllowUsers` in a file. 
I've got that part covered with `sed -e 's/^\s*#\?AllowUsers.*//'`
But the thing I'm having trouble with is that it should leave one occurrence in the file and remove everything else.

Let me know, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add an input example and desired output example

Comment: This is probably better done with `awk`

Comment: Seems yo are right, I've been looking for a `sed` option but seems `awk '/AllowUsers||#AllowUsers||# AllowUsers/&&c++ {next} 1'` does exactly what it needs to do!

Answer (score 1):

`awk '/AllowUsers||#AllowUsers||# AllowUsers/&&c++ {next} 1'` did the job!

Comment: It should be `|`, not `||`, otherwise you are just matching empty patterns.